# How can I make Puppet generate my /etc/security/access.conf based on a variable?

Tags: puppet

I want to be able to dynamically say what local users have access to the server. This should generate a /etc/security/access.conf file as such:

```
+ : root : ALL
# Next lines should be generated dynamically based on a variable
+ : user1 : ALL
+ : user2 : ALL
+ : user3 : ALL
# Until this line
- : ALL : ALL
```

I know that I can use a single variable in a access.conf template, e.g. placing a line of:

```
+ : <%=local_accepted_user1%> : ALL
```

But how can I make this work for multiple users using an array?

Comment: There are examples of how to use iteration and loops in the template docs.  Have you reviewed that?  Did you have specific questions?  http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to this in order to allow both arrays and strings to be passed in.  We have used this in multiple templates in puppet.

1. Ensure that the variable passed in becomes an array
2. Iterate over the array

```
+ : root : ALL
# Next lines should be generated dynamically based on a variable
<%
    if @users.class == String then
      real_users = [@users]
    else
      real_users = @users
    end

    # flatten ensures that any inline arrays are also processed by element
    real_users.flatten.each { |cur_user|
-%>
+ : <%= @cur_user -%> : ALL
<% 
    }
-%>
# Until this line
- : ALL : ALL
```